# Dúvida na conversão de SQL para Django ORM

Tags: django, orm

Olá!

Estou estudando iniciando em Django ORM e gostaria de ajuda para converter o SQL abaixo, pois não estou conseguindo realizar as junções necessárias. Segue:

```
SELECT P.nome, T.nome FROM 
professor as D 
INNER JOIN pessoa_fisica AS PF ON (D.pessoa_fisica_id = PF.pessoa_id) 
INNER JOIN pessoa AS P ON (PF.pessoa_id = P.id)
INNER JOIN funcionario AS F ON(F.pessoafisica_id = PF.pessoa_ptr_id) 
INNER JOIN ocupacao AS S ON(S.funcionario_id = F.pessoafisica_id)
INNER JOIN Titulo as T on (S.titulacao_id = T.id) ORDER BY p.nome
```

Qual a melhor forma de realizar isso em Django ORM?

Obrigado!

Comment: Bem vindo. Poste aqui o que você já tentou até agora.

Comment: Olá, Leonardo! Obrigado pela resposta. Segue umas das minhas últimas tentativas: `qs = Professor.objects.filter(pessoa_fisica__pessoa_funcionario_ocupacao__titulo)

NameError: name 'pessoa_fisica__pessoa__funcionario__ocupacao__titulo' is not defined
`

Comment: Olá, Leonardo! Cheguei a uma conclusão, em conversas com outras pessoas. Foi usado uma estratégia com 'values_list'. Mesmo assim sigo com algumas dúvidas e confusões com do Django ORM... creio que o tempo irá diminuir essa questões. Segue a solução para o meu caso: `qs = Professor.objects.all().values_list('pessoa_fisica__nome','pessoa_fisica__funcionario__ocupacao__titulo__nome') `